# Is there a way to run a standby service in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm setup with a typical web app stack (nginx & php). I need redis as a service in docker swarm. The swarm has 2 nodes and each node should have the web stack and redis service. But only one redis container should be active at a time (and be able to communicate on with each web stack), the other one must be there but in standby mode so that if the first redis fails, this one could switch quickly.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with docker swarm, having a backup, standby container would be considered anti-pattern. A more recommended approach to deploy a reliable container using swarm would be to have a [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#healthcheck) command as part of your `Dockerfile`. You can set a specific interval after which the `healthcheck` commands comes into effect for your container to be able to warm up.

Now, club the `HEALTHCHECK` functionality with the fact that `docker-swarm` always maintains the specified number of contianers. Make your `healthcheck` script throw the exit code 1 if it becomes `unhealthy`. As soon as the swarm detects exit code 1, it kills the container and to maintain the number of containers, it spins up a new one.

The entire process takes only milliseconds and works seamlessly. Have multiple containers in case the warm-up time is long. This will prevent your service from becoming unavailable if one of the containers goes down.

Example of a `healthcheck` command:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

Comment: That's already automatically set up if you specify the number of replicas. Yes it will try to keep that many replicas. I don't really care if it's anti-pattern. Also you said "Have multiple containers in case the warm-up time is long", it is to long and I'm asking how to achieve that. I need redis replication across all the nodes but only one redis container is actually working with all other app stacks across the nodes. And if something happens to that one redis container, the other one can step in instantly.

Comment: @CzipO2: If you don't care then, have the traffic to `reddis` directed to a load balancer (like `nginx` or `HAProxy`) that would act as a reverse proxy to your two `reddis` containers. Have these reverse proxy switch the traffic route from one container to the other in case of failure.

Comment: @CzipO2: Did it help?

Comment: I still haven't checked, I'm having some trouble.